# Twitter double encode entity references?

Tags: twitter

Why is twitter double encoding XML entity references?

Here's an example tweet:

```
xml entity ref test < & '
```

The response from statuses/friends_timeline:

```
<status>
  <created_at>Wed Jun 24 00:16:15 +0000 2009</created_at>
  <id>2302770346</id>
  <text>xml entity ref test &amp;lt; &amp; '</text>
  <source>web</source>
  <truncated>false</truncated>
```

shouldn't it be

```
&lt; &amp; &apos;
```

I did some more test, here's what happens in the http post to send the update:

> sniff again < & '

post data:

```
authenticity_token=secret_sauce_removed&status=sniff+again+%3C+%26+'&twttr=true&return_rendered_status=true
```

I've confirmed Justin's observation that only < > is double encoded. First line is the xml repsonse, 2nd line json.

```
 <text>&quot; &amp; ' &amp;lt; &amp;gt;</text>
"text":"\" & ' &lt; &gt;"
```

Twitter documentation says "escaped and HTML encoded status body", I guess escaped means xml encoding < >.

But i still don't understand why they're doing it.  No web pages are involved in the whole process.  The tweet is sent through the rest API url-encoded, and it is retrieved as xml or json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's double coded because the text property is quasi HTML Encoded text (looks like they're only encoding < and > so that you don't start/end a new html element in your tweet). Therefore, before the XML parses it for communication across the wire, you'd have:

```
xml entity ref test &lt; & '
```

That string then gets encoded again (so that when it is decoded, it is still the proper HTML Encoded text) which turns it in to the:

```
xml entity ref test &amp;lt; &amp; '
```

That you are getting back.

Comment: Is there a way to stop twitter from doing this? Say my status is V%C3%A6rdibevis (this is Danish). Twitter accepts this as V%25C3%25A6rdibevis which is really !@# annoying ;)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's taking the HTML code, and sticking that inside of an XML field, so when you use your XML parser on the XML, you get valid HTML.

Comment: Then why isn't it also double-encoding '&' to '&amp;amp;' ?

Comment: It's not encoding the & to &amp;amp; because the first round of encoding isn't really HTML Encoding. It's just removing characters that, if rendered, would start/end a new html element.